# Returning list from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-volley

This is a method for returning a custom list. However I am updating the list inside a async task (OnResponse). I had to use a nested volley request. I have declared a list item but am unable to use it inside the OnRespose method. Can anyone help me with this? How can I return the list item from the method.

```
private ArrayList<sItem> fetchApiData(){

    ArrayList<sItem> list= new ArrayList<>();
    String url="http://www.gadgetsinnepal.com.np/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/";

    JsonArrayRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


                    try {

                        // Parsing json array response
                        // loop through each json object

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            sItem sitem=new sItem();

                            JSONObject item = (JSONObject) response
                                    .get(i);
                            String id = item.getString("id");
                            sitem.id=id;
                            String date = item.getString("date");

                            JSONObject titleobj = item
                                    .getJSONObject("title");
                            String title= titleobj.getString("rendered");
                            sitem.title=title;
                            String featuredMedia= item.getString("featured_media");


                            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                                    "http://www.gadgetsinnepal.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/"+featuredMedia, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject nested_response) {

                                    try {
                                        JSONObject guilld = nested_response.getJSONObject("guid");
                                        String featured_img_url = guilld.getString("rendered");
                                        sitem.img=featured_img_url;
                                        list.add(sitem);
                                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"IMAGE :" + list.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "ERROR "+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"network timeout error",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                                        //TODO
                                    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                                        //TODO
                                    } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                                        //TODO
                                    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                                        //TODO
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                                    7000,
                                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

                            MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);


                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a closure variable inside a listener, you need to mark the variable final when declaring it. This is okay for a list since a final list can still be manipulated internally (you can add/remove items from it).

`final ArrayList<sItem> list = new ArrayList<>();`

However, you probably still won't get your result because of the asynchronous behavior. The main, wrapping function returns the list immediately; even before Volley kicks off the network requests. It is only filled in later by a Volley response sometime in the future.

A call to `fetchApiData()` (as it is written now) will always return the empty list. (However, it is a reference, so depending on how you use it, it may be filled in later, but this is bad design and will almost always be used wrong by any consumer of the function.)

Instead, you should probably provide an interface or callback function to the `fetchApiData()` parameter list, and then call that function once you are finished filling in the list from the network responses.

Note: Because you have nested calls, you will also need to track when all the nested calls are finished, and in each nested `onResponse` check so that when it is the last call to respond, it will finally kick off the callback.

Then, whatever calls fetchApiData() with a callback, will know that when that callback it supplied is called, that the list will be filled completely.

Comment: If its not too much to ask..  What would the correct design look like?

Comment: @NipeshKc It gets messy to implement. I would actually suggest as an alternative you look into Observables via RxJava/RxAndroid instead. Would make this whole thing a lot simpler to write and understand. (Once you get over the Observable and Rx learning curve.)

Answer (score 0):

declare your list as final, or as a global field